# Alert kubernetes deployments not healthy GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, alert

I'm trying to find a way to trigger a webhook if the number of healthy deployment replicas are below a certain threshold. Is this possible without using prometheus and kube-state-metrics?

Comment: You could write your own app using kubernets clinet.